# When I update vuejs3 to v3.2.40 why am I getting the error "An index signature parameter type must be either string or number"?

Tags: vuejs3, visual-studio-2022, npm-update

I am trying to simply upgrade the version of vue3 we are running at work from v3.2.31 to v3.2.40. However, when I do, I am now getting an error in the runtime-dom.d.ts

Below is a screen shot from the file with vue v3.2.31 installed.
[image]

Once I've run the "npm update vue --save" command, the file looks like this (v3.2.40)...
[image]

...and VS 2022 throws the following error when trying to build...
[image]

If I delete the line from my local copy of runtime-dom.d.ts, all works as before. My problem comes when deploying the solution to the development environment etc. The npm install step puts a version of the runtime-dom.d.ts that does still have this line.

I'd like to fix this without having to resort to hacking the runtime-dom.d.ts file if at all possible.

Many thanks in advance.